# How to assign value to variable in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, variable-assignment, assign

In trying to test for the failure of a command in a Makefile (in this case `jekyll build relative`), the variable `$$?` should contain the exit code of the last command. In testing, this code is shown to be 127. However, I would like to assign it to the variable `LAST_EXIT` so that an the next if statement can check whether the executed command succeeded or failed.

The problem is that `LAST_EXIT` never receives the value it is being assigned, as shown in the code below. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

**Code:**

```
LAST_EXIT = 0

all:
    @echo "Building the website... Running command:"
    - jekyll build relative || LAST_EXIT=$$?
    - jekyll build relative || echo $$? and $(LAST_EXIT)
ifeq ($(LAST_EXIT), 0)
    #echo a message indicating success
```

Output:

```
jekyll build relative || LAST_EXIT=$?
/bin/sh: jekyll: command not found
jekyll build relative || echo $? and 0
/bin/sh: jekyll: command not found
127 and 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach.

1) Make resolves conditional parts of the makefile before it executes any rule. This:

```
all:
    LAST_EXIT=0
ifeq ($(LAST_EXIT), 0)
    #echo a message indicating success 
endif
```

will not report success (unless you set the value of `LAST_EXIT` somewhere above the rule).

2) Each command in a recipe executes in its own subshell; shell variable values are *not* preserved from one line to the next:

```
all:
    LAST_EXIT=5; echo the value is $$LAST_EXIT
    @echo now the value is $$LAST_EXIT
```

This should work:

```
all:
    - jekyll build relative || LAST_EXIT=$$?; \
  if [ $$LAST_EXIT == 0 ]; then  echo success!; fi
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I'm using a different system than you are, so running your Makefile code resulted in this error: `/bin/sh: line 0: [: ==: unary operator expected` I ended up solving this problem by just writing a script that checks if Jekyll is installed or not. The `if ... fi` format works fine in my bash script, although I had to modify the equality test.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was calling the following script in the Makefile to check for Jekyll:
(called as `./{scriptName`}

```
#!/bin/bash

LINEBREAK="*****************************************************************"
VERSION=0

echo "Checking Jekyll..."
VERSION=$(jekyll --version)

if test "$?" == "0"
then
     echo "$VERSION is installed on this system..."
else
     echo "$LINEBREAK"
     echo "Oops! It looks like you don't have Jekyll yet, lets install it!"
     echo "Running command: \"sudo gem install jekyll\""
     echo "$LINEBREAK"
     sudo gem install jekyll
     if test "$?" != "0"
     then
          echo "$LINEBREAK"
          echo "Jekyll install failed... It needs to be installed as a super-user on your system, which"
          echo "requires your password. You can run \"sudo gem install jekyll\" yourself to install Jekyll."
          echo "You can also see their website at: \"https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/\" for more information"
          echo "$LINEBREAK"
          exit 113
     else
          echo "$LINEBREAK"
          echo "Jekyll has been installed on this system..."
          echo "Proceeding to build..."
          echo "$LINEBREAK"
     fi
fi

exit 0
```